# How do you prevent case-folding on an external XMPP component?

Tags: java, xmpp

We are working on an XMPP external component provided by Tinder/Whack and want to preserve the case.  For example, if the JID is Bob@myhost.com, we do not want to translate as bob@myhost.com.  We see the jids coming across to the external component as Bob@myhost.com, but by the time they reach our specific code, they get folded to bob@myhost.com.  We need to preserve the case.

What is the best way of preserving the case of the JID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "localpart" of a JID is currently defined in [RFC 6122, section 2.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6122#section-2.3), which refers to Appendix A, which [says](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6122#appendix-A.3):

> A.3.  Mapping
>
> This profile specifies mapping using the following tables from [STRINGPREP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3454#appendix-B.2):
>
> ```
> Table B.1
> Table B.2
> ```

Note that Table B.2 of STRINGPREP is ugly, hard-coded case folding.  So no, you can't turn off case folding for comparison of JIDs, and many servers and libraries will modify JIDs that they process to avoid having to perform costly normalization multiple times.

If you would like for this to change, we're working on a new string comparison framework in the [précis working group](http://datatracker.ietf.org/wg/precis/charter/) at the IETF, and welcome input - but backward compatibility requirements will make yours a difficult position to argue.

Comment: Curiously what are other component developers doing for legacy transports where case is important?  I could use a custom element but wanted to use as much as base XMPP as possible.

Comment: @Zash - that might work.  The bad thing is we use the nickname field for the display name.  Right now, we have decided to encode upper case characters and then decode when we need the upper case again.  This is not ideal, but will work for now.

Comment: @MattJ: nope.  XEP-106 is only defined for the ten characters:
<space>"&'/:<>@\
anything else is not an escape sequence.

Comment: @JoeHildebrand Wow, good catch. Learn something new every day :)

Comment: @MattJ: I cheated by having written XEP-106. :)